# LaravelSession::insertUpdate() issues while using laravel moltin shopping cart

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to use [Moltin Cart](https://github.com/moltin/laravel-cart) in my Laravel 4 app:

- I installed Moltin Cart through composer,
- then added the Service Provider ('Moltin\Cart\CartServiceProvider')
- and added the aliases ('Cart' => 'Moltin\Cart\Facade').

Now I want only logged in users to access the cart so I added

```
$this->beforeFilter('auth', array('only' => 'postAddToCart', 'getCart', 'getRemoveItem'));
```

in my storeController.

But I get this error when I try to access

```
Declaration of Moltin\Cart\Storage\LaravelSession::insertUpdate() must be compatible with Moltin\Cart\StorageInterface::insertUpdate(Moltin\Cart\Item\Line $item)
```

My Store Controller is :

```
<?php

class StoresController extends \BaseController {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->beforeFilter('csrf', array('on' => 'post'));
    $this->beforeFilter('auth', array('only' => 'postAddToCart', 'getCart', 'getRemoveItem'));
}

public function getIndex()
{
    return  View::make('stores.index')
                    ->with('products', Product::take(4)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get());
}

public function getView($id)
{
    return  View::make('stores.view')
                    ->with('product', Product::find($id));
}

public function getCategory($category_id)
{
    return  View::make('stores.category')
                    ->with('products', Product::where('category_id', '=', $category_id)->paginate(6))
                    ->with('category', Category::find($category_id));   
}

public function getSearch()
{
    $keyword = Input::get('keyword');
    return  View::make('stores.search')
                    ->with('products', Product::where('title', 'LIKE', '%'. $keyword . '%')->get())
                    ->with('keyword', $keyword);
}

public function postAddToCart()
{
    $product    = Product::find(Input::get('id'));
    $qunatity = Input::get('qunatity');

    Cart::insert(array(
        'id'                => $product->id,
        'name'          => $product->name,
        'price'         => $product->price,
        'qunatity'  => $qunatity,
        'image'         => $product->image
    ));

    return Redirect::to('store/cart');
}

public function getCart()
{
    return View::make('stores.cart')->with('products', Cart::contents());
}

public function getRemoveItem($identifier)
{
    $product = Cart::item($identifier);
    $product->remove();
    return Redirect::to('store/cart');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### The short answer:

Resume your installation assuming that **moltin/cart** and **moltin/laravel-cart** repositories are in sync.

### The long answer:

As the error message states:

- `Moltin\Cart\StorageInterface::insertUpdate(Moltin\Cart\Item\Line $item)`
- `Moltin\Cart\Storage\LaravelSession::insertUpdate()`

don't have the same signature.

They should be in sync! The issue has nothing to do at all with your `StoresController`.

I checked:

- https://github.com/moltin/cart/blob/master/src/Moltin/Cart/StorageInterface.php and
- https://github.com/moltin/laravel-cart/blob/master/src/Moltin/Cart/Storage/LaravelSession.php

I find out that the signatures are OK as the time of my answer post.

---

```
namespace Moltin\Cart;

interface StorageInterface
{
    /**
     * Add or update an item in the cart
     * 
     * @param  Item   $item The item to insert or update
     * @return void
     */
    public function insertUpdate(Item $item); // <<<< This is it!

    ...
```

}

---

```
namespace Moltin\Cart\Storage;

use Moltin\Cart\Item;
...

class LaravelSession implements \Moltin\Cart\StorageInterface
{
    ...

    /**
     * Add or update an item in the cart
     * 
     * @param  Item   $item The item to insert or update
     * @return void
     */
    public function insertUpdate(Item $item)  // <<<< This is it!
    {
        ...
    }

    ...

}
```

---

My guess is that you did your install when the repositories (knowing that **moltin/cart** is a dependency of **moltin/laravel-cart**) were not in sync for some reason.